# Related products are not visible on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on magento ultimo theme version 1.15. Related products slider is not shown on my detail page.
Please help me guys what to do.
I dont under stand whats the issue.
www.crewebserver.com/~wwwclearance/index.php/manufacturers/9a19-omni-300-led-35k-gu24.html

Thanks

Comment: Go to System -> Index Management re-index data

Comment: if its not resolve your issue then call `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>`  in your product page where you want to display related products.

Comment: Apart from re-indexing your data, please check whether related.phtml file is being called in product view page in frontend or not.

Comment: Its visible , but showing on full width..

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b05zgatb9

Comment: Please help me  why its not working as thumbnail slider. ?

Comment: seems its issue of design related issues